# Initializing Enums in Hibernate and Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, enums

I have one simple class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer Id;
    @Length(min = 5, message = "Username must be at least 5 characters long.")
    @Column(name="username",nullable=false,unique=true)
    private String userName;
    @ManyToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="user_user_profile")
    private Set<UserProfile> userProfile = new HashSet<>();
}
```

And second class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profile")
public class UserProfile {
    @javax.persistence.Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int Id;

    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserProfileType type = UserProfileType.USER;
}

public enum UserProfileType {
    USER("USER"),
    ADMIN("ADMIN");
}
```

I'm using Spring MVC and Spring Secuirty with Hibernate. Is there any way to on start of the app make every possible entry in `UserProfile` Entity (there is only two)? Do I have to get `UserProfile` from database (via `TypedQuery` or `EntityManager.find()` ) and then add it to the User to not make any exceptions?

Comment: Usually I add a listener for the spring context start-up event. When I get the event I do all the initialization operations I need. Here you can find how to build listeners https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2 I suggest to you to use the `@EventListener` annotation

Answer (score 1):

The enum items are static in your application, so I wouldn't try to make automatic changes in the database. Adding a new record is trivial, but removing an item that is already referenced may need individual care. These values are essential for your application, so I think they should be included in your SQL scripts.

If you are using DB versioning tools such as Flyway or Liquibase, add/remove records of the `user_profile` table in the migration scripts. They can be configured to run the migrations before your application (and Hibernate) starts, so the application will always see the correct data.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a application start up event and persist the user profiles. You can delete all the user profiles before the application shut down as well. But I wouldn't recommend this as I assume the UserProfiles wouldn't change frequently. If that is the case, you are better off preloading the user profiles via some sql script as suggested in the other answer. If you really want to do it via app, the safest way would be to delete before the app gets shut down. Following is the sample snippet. I assume you are using spring-data-jpa and provided the snippet.

```
@Component
public class AppStartedListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        for(UserProfileType userProfileType: UserProfileType.values()) {
            UserProfile up = new UserProfile(userProfileType);
            repository.save(up);                
        }      
    }
}


@Component
public class AppStoppedListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        repository.deleteAll();
    }
}

public interface UserProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<UserProfile, Integer> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I added method to dao layer:

```
@Transactional
@EventListener
public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
   UserProfile user=new UserProfile();
   em.persist(user);
   UserProfile admin=new UserProfile();
   admin.setType(UserProfileType.ADMIN);
   em.persist(admin);
}
```

And now, before adding new User i just use HQL to get persistent UserProfile object that I can add to my User. Altough it works I will probably try to load it from some sort of *.sql file since I had to add method metioned above to the Dao layer interface (because of interface type proxy) and I don't like it to be honest.